# MongoDB update JsonValidator with NodeJS keeps failing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, json-schema-validator

Cannot seem to figure out why json validation for my db update/upsert operations keep failing both in Node server app and directly in the MongoDB shell. I could be missing something but have no idea what that could be.

I am using MongoDB Atlas. At the moment, updates are only successful when I remove the db.createCollection validator option parameter.

But schema validation is crucial for this use-case.

```
ERROR :::: MongoError: Document failed validation
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:261:20) 
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at MessageStream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)  
    at processIncomingData (..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)      
    at MessageStream._write (..\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)       
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:428:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:412:5)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:302:11)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:722:22)       
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:476:20)      
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)       
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:166:17) {
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 
4, high_: 1591981465 },
  ok: 0,
  code: 121,
  codeName: 'DocumentValidationFailure',
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 
4, high_: 1591981465 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  name: 'MongoError'
}
```

Code:

```
const email = Object.freeze([{
    value: 'p',
    status: 'active'
}, {
    value: 'b',
    status: 'defunct'
}, {
    value: 'o'
    status: 'active'
}, {
    value: 'w'
    status: 'inactive'
}]);

const schema = Object.freeze({
    additionalProperties: false,
    bsonType: 'object',
    description: 'email data point',
    properties: {
        _id: {
            bsonType: 'objectId'
        },
        address: {
            bsonType: 'string',
            maxLength: 64,
            pattern: '^\w+@\w+(.\w+)+$',
            description: 'required: email address'
        },
        contactTypes: {
            bsonType: 'array',
            description: 'required: a set of unique string values',
            items: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                enum: email.map( e => e.value )
            },
            uniqueItems: true
        },
        dateCreated: {
            bsonType: 'long',
            description: 'required: contact email creation timestamp in ms since epoch'
       },
        isPrimary: {
            bsonType: 'bool'
       },
        lastUpdated: {
            bsonType: 'long',
            description: 'contact email recent update timestamp in ms since epoch'
        }
    },
    required: [ 'address', 'contactTypes', 'dateCreated', 'isPrimary' ]
});

// db connection logic

const colName = 'emails';

db.createCollection( colName, {
    validator: {
        $jsonSchema: { ...schema }
    }
});

const doc = {
    address: 'adfadfslkds@ffk.co.uk',
    contactTypes: [ 'p', 'b' ],
    isPrimary: true,
};

let updated;

( async () => {
    try {
        updated = await db.collection( colName ).findOneAndUpdate( doc, {
            $set: {
                ...doc,  
                dateCreated: Date.now()
           }
        }, {
            returnNewDocument: true,
            upsert: true
        });
    } catch( e ) {
        console.error( e.message );
    }
})();
```

Identical request using Mongo shell:

```
MongoDB Enterprise D0-shard-0:PRIMARY> db.emails.findOneAndUpdate({
    address: 'adfadfslkds@ffk.co.uk',
    contactTypes: [ 'p', 'b' ],
    isPrimary: true
}, {
    $set: {
        address: 'adfadfslkds@ffk.co.uk',
        contactTypes: [ 'p', 'b' ],
        isPrimary: true,
        dateCreated: 1591981465
    }
}, {
    returnNewDocument: true,
    upsert: true
})
```

Resulted in:

```
2020-06-12T12:33:47.785-0700 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591990428, 24),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation",
    "code" : 121,
    "codeName" : "DocumentValidationFailure",
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591990428, 24),   
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"9QzeeWQw4kYtnf1m/2dTyvNphAQ="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6798592801870184449")
        }
    }
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DBCollection.prototype.findAndModify@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:725:15
DBCollection.prototype.findOneAndUpdate@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:900:12
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: The error returned should give a bit of detail about which part of the rule failed.

Comment: I have now also updated the post with a copy of the returned mongodb validation error object.

Comment: That looks like node wrapped the error and didn't include the full error message.  Can we see a sample document that fails validation?

Comment: When I removed the schema validation and ran the code, something like the following was successfully stored in the `emails` collection: `{ _id: objectId(...),
    address: 'adfadfslkds@ffk.co.uk',
    contactTypes: [ 'p', 'b' ],
    isPrimary: true,    dateCreated: 1591981465
}`

Comment: @Joe, I just ran same command using the MongoDB shell and appended the details in the post as well. The result is somewhat similar to the node version.

Answer (score 1):

`bsonType: 'int'` is a 32-bit integer.  That is not big enough to hold the number of milliseconds since epoch.

You should use `bsonType: 'long'` for that.

**Edit**

The dateCreated in the sample document, `dateCreated: 1591981465` is `int`, not `long` so it won't match.

If you want to allow both types, use `type: "number"` instead of `bsonType: "long"`

Javascript uses the backslash for escaping in string values.  In order to get a literal backslash in a string, you need to double it, like:

pattern: '^\\w+@\\w+(.\\w+)+$'

Comment: I have set timestamp bsonType to long. The problem is still there though. Many thanks for pointing out that timestamp bsonType thing. Can't believe I missed that. facepalm.

Comment: I have since returned to the (\\\) pattern as shown in your edit - it was the original pattern. But I tried (\\) temporarily as a test. It didn't work. So I discarded that idea. As for the dateCreated, I think "long" is a more robust option for the long run.